# installing Ubuntu on windows10

Tags: windows-10

my laptop has `windows10` and I am trying to install Ubuntu as well (from `USB`). I have 2 partitions and when I try to install Ubuntu, at some point I will reach to a page which is called "`installation type`". at this point I have to choose "`Device for boot loader installation`" but when I press "install now" it does not go to the next step because the only option I can see here is "`/dev/sda`" and if I press "`install now`" it would give this error:

```
no boot file system is defined
please correct this from the partitioning menu
```

but the problem is that I do not have any option. do you know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Is this the issue? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: Sounds as if you selected `Something else` during installation, take a look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation) how to use it.